# What is the name of this dial/spinner-like interface element?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, interface

[image]
[image]

I've tried googling both spinner and dial, but they turn up results that are not this. I need to implement this in a website, and would like to know the pattern for it -- it's just so much easier to use than drop downs on mobile. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's known as picker or spinner. First example looks like a custom designed one, but it can be done with [this tutorial](https://isujith.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/horizontal-uipickerview/), your second example is the native [iOS6 picker](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_the_UIPickerView_and_UIDatePicker_Components_%28iOS_6%29) (now it has changed to a flat look)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

They are just called date pickers in iOS guidelines.
Android generally terms them Pickers for both date and time.

These are just customizations of already existing spinners. Essentially, the underlying concept is the same. Only the visual representation is different. So, as far as I researched I don't think they are named different.

[Do spinner-based date pickers on iOS & Android detract from the user's experience?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22893/do-spinner-based-date-pickers-on-ios-android-detract-from-the-users-experienc)

In another stack exchange question, it was called Spinner based date pickers. Link provided above for reference